# antd Table onRow onClick to another component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, antd

I have an antd table displaying my data. However, how would I ensure that when the user clicks on a specific row, it will redirect him to a new component named "ViewLog" with the row data?

Code that I provided below doesn't work:

```
 <Table bordered
        className="components-table-demo-nested"
        onRow={(i) => ({
          onClick: (e) => {
              return <Link to={"/admin/ViewLog"}></Link>;
            },
          })}
        columns={columns}
        expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
        dataSource={data}
        size="small"
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code as following and your code might work:

```
onRow={(i) => ({
    onClick: (e) => 
        history.push('/admin/ViewLog')
})}
```

Comment: the second one, w/o return works but not the <Link>

Comment: What you want to do with the <Link>? Are you going to redirect to another page? If so you should use history.push instead

Comment: thanks for the solution! history.push is the correct way!

Answer (score 0):

you could also use useNavigate hook from react-router-dom if you have your route defined. It also allows you to pass the state through which you can retain row data